# Using user input value to display a specific object from an array list

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to create a program where the user inputs animal pertinent values, which then create animal Objects, which are then saved into an array list. The area I am having trouble with is shown below. After the Array list is populated, I cannot figure out how to use the user input (select) to find that values index within the array list. (int index = animalList.indexOf(?))

Would appreciate any help

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  List <Animal> animalList = new ArrayList <Animal>();
    char ans;

do{  // User input
  Animal animal = new Animal(); // arraylist

   System.out.println("Animal's 'common' name: ");
     animal.setName(in.next());

   System.out.println("Animal's class: ");
     animal.setAnmlClass(in.next());

   System.out.println("Vertabrate or Invertabrate: ");
     animal.setCharVert(in.next());

   System.out.println("Warm or Cold blooded: ");
     animal.setCharBld(in.next());

   System.out.println("Animal's habitat (general): ");
     animal.setCharHab(in.next());

   System.out.println("Would you like to enter in a new animal (y/n)? ");
     String answer = in.next();
        ans = answer.charAt(0);

    animalList.add(animal);

  }while(ans == 'y');

   System.out.println("Enter the animal you wish to view: ");
     String select = in.next();
     System.out.println(select);
     int index =  animalList.indexOf( ? );
     System.out.println(index);
```

Comment: indexOf won't get you what you want.  Essentially, there's no way for the user to input a string that will end up satisfying `Animal.equal()`.

Comment: Does `Animal` class have overridden `equals()` based on `name`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you need a custom method for this with a while loop:

```
public int getIndexWithName(List<Animal> animals, String name){
    for (int index = 0; index < animals.size(); index++){
       if (name.equals(animals.get(index).getName())){
           return index;
       }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

And use this:

```
int index =  getIndexWithName(animalList, select);
//Do some validation check
if (index < 0){
    //Give some error message
    System.out.println("That's not a common name I recognize!");
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I used a bit of what you suggested in my own way (had static non-static issues), anyways... I am a novice, so it may not be pretty, but it works... Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You might consider making a HashTable  instead of a List, with the animal name as the key.

Comment: Thank you, the only problem is one of the specs for this project is using an Array List. If that wasn't a must, I would have gone with the Hash.

Comment: Use a `HashMap<K,V>` and **not** a `HashTable<K,V>`

Answer (score 0):

```
 System.out.println("Enter the name of the animal you wish to view: ");
 String select = in.next();
 System.out.println(select); // Check that your toString() its proper
 //There's not a straight way to find each animal's index
// so you 'll have to write an int getIndex(select) method to do that and then you 'll call it
 int index = getIndext(select);
 System.out.println("The animal you chose has index: "+index);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a **`HashMap<String, Animal>`** that maps an animal's name to the object.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
List <Animal> animalList = new ArrayList <Animal>();

Map<String, Animal> map = new HashMap<>();

char ans;

do{  // User input
  Animal animal = new Animal(); // arraylist

 System.out.println("Animal's 'common' name: ");

 String name = in.next();
 animal.setName(name);
 map.put(name, animal);

System.out.println("Animal's class: ");
 animal.setAnmlClass(in.next());

System.out.println("Vertabrate or Invertabrate: ");
 animal.setCharVert(in.next());

System.out.println("Warm or Cold blooded: ");
 animal.setCharBld(in.next());

System.out.println("Animal's habitat (general): ");
 animal.setCharHab(in.next());

System.out.println("Would you like to enter in a new animal (y/n)? ");
 String answer = in.next();
    ans = answer.charAt(0);

animalList.add(animal);

}while(ans == 'y');

System.out.println("Enter the animal you wish to view: ");
 String select = in.next();
 System.out.println(map.get(select));
```

Answer (score 0):

With help from Roel & Theodora, I ended up with this. It may not be the cleanest or "prettiest" way to do this, but it works with no issues.
System.out.println("Enter the animal you wish to view: ");
         String select = in.next();

```
 for (int index = 0; index < animalList.size(); index++){

 if (select.equals(animalList.get(index).getName())){
     System.out.println(index);

     System.out.format("%n"); // aesthetic break
     System.out.print(animalList.get(index).getName()+": ");
     System.out.print(animalList.get(index).getAnmlClass()+", ");
     System.out.print(animalList.get(index).getCharVert()+", ");
     System.out.print(animalList.get(index).getCharBld()+" Blooded, ");
     System.out.print(animalList.get(index).getCharHab()+" Terrain");
     System.out.format("%n"); // aesthetic break
   }
 else{
     System.out.println("The Zoo does not house that animal currently");
 }
 }
```